# Someone please explain cosine similarity equation to me?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vectors, inner-products

I'm trying to understand the [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) in a simple and graphical way, very much similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746501/can-someone-give-an-example-of-cosine-similarity-in-a-very-simple-graphical-wa) but I do not understand how the person got to their answer.

Comment: The link has multiple answers to several questions. Please try harder to ask a question.

Comment: Two vectors define a two dimensional subspace; so you could just draw the relationship on a piece of paper.  Perhaps I am missing a deeper question?

Comment: thank you for answering, I think they way i phrased the question was odd however someone managed to answer it exactly how i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vectors are $(x_1 \  x_2 \  x_3 \  x_4 \  x_5 \   x_6 \  x_7 \  x_8)^T=(2 \  0 \  1 \  1 \  0 \  \  2 \  1 \  1)^T$ and $(y_1 \  y_2 \  y_3 \  y_4 \  y_5 \   y_6 \  y_7 \  y_8)^T=( \ 2 \  1 \  1 \  0 \  1 \  1 \  1 \  1)^T$

The cosine of angle ($\alpha$) between the two vectors  is $cos(\alpha)=\large{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^8 x_i\cdot y_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^8 x_i^2}\cdot \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^8 y_i^2}}}=\frac{2\cdot 2+0 \cdot 1+ 1\cdot 1+ 1\cdot 0 + 0 \cdot 1+ 2\cdot 1+ 1\cdot 1+ 1\cdot 1}{\sqrt{2^2+0^2+1^2+1^2+0^2+2^2+1^2+1^2}\cdot \sqrt{2^2+1^2+1^2+0^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2}}$

$=\frac{4+1+2+1+1}{\sqrt{4+1+1+4+1+1}\cdot \sqrt{4+1+1+1+1+1+1}}=\frac{9}{\sqrt{12}\cdot \sqrt{10}}=0.8216$

Thus the equation is $\cos(\alpha)=0.8216$

$\alpha=arcos(0.8216)=34.76°$

Comment: thank you so much for your help!!!!

Comment: You´re welcome.